# Comment on a hadith by Aischa r.a where Umar r.a wanted from the wives of the prophet to veil themselve

Tags: hadith-interpretation, women, islamic-basis, hijab

Salam alaykum, i would like to hear your opinion on this following hadith which i found on a website:

> It was narrated from ‘Aa’ishah that the wives of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to go out at night to al-Manaasi’ (well known places in the direction of al-Baqee’) to relieve themselves and ‘Umar used to say to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), “Let your wives be veiled.” But the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) did not do that. Then one night Sawdah bint Zam’ah, the wife of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), went out at ‘Isha’ time and she was a tall woman. ‘Umar called out to her: “We have recognized you, O Sawdah!” hoping that hijab would be revealed, then Allaah revealed the verse of hijab.

Because i have doubts relating to this hadith. Because it seems so that Umar R.A intendently wanted that woman should veil themselves.

This is also commonly used as an argument against islam so it would be in favour of me to clear my doubt and to answer knowledgably to others who try to seek the more deeper meaning of this hadith.

Question: is Umar r.a the cause that woman veil themselves?

Visisted websites:

https://seekersguidance.org/answers/general-counsel/understand-relation-umar-verse-regarding-hijab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hadith simply shows that Umar (RA) had a deep understanding of Islam such that he could recognize what was good even before Allah gave a clear command regarding it.

It does not mean that Umar (RA) is the reason something happened but rather that Umar (RA) understood what was in line with Islam. Allah confirmed what Umar (RA) said because it was in line with Islam and Allah was going to reveal it anyway.

So, Umar (RA) did not cause its revelation but he predicted it.

> `Umar said, "I agreed with Allah in three things," or said, "My Lord
> agreed with me in three things.
>
> I said, 'O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Would that you took the station of
> Abraham as a place of prayer.'
>
> I also said, 'O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Good and bad persons visit you!
> Would that you ordered the Mothers of the believers to cover
> themselves with veils.' So the Divine Verses of Al-Hijab (i.e. veiling
> of the women) were revealed.
>
> I came to know that the Prophet (ﷺ) had blamed some of his wives so I
> entered upon them and said, 'You should either stop (troubling the
> Prophet (ﷺ) ) or else Allah will give His Apostle better wives than
> you.'
>
> When I came to one of his wives, she said to me, 'O `Umar! Does
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) haven't what he could advise his wives with,
> that you try to advise them?' "
>
> Thereupon Allah revealed:-- "It may be, if he divorced you (all) his
> Lord will give him instead of you, wives better than you Muslims (who
> submit to Allah).." (66.5) ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/65/10))

Comment: Barak Allahu feek this helped me a lot!

Answer (score -3):

Umar did intend to invent the law of Hijab. The incident was where Umar saw Sauda attending the call of nature in the evening and recognised her. Umar used to insist about the Hijab for many times but when he saw Sauda attending the call of nature he was furious about this incident and he severely scolded the prophet and forced him to institute the law.

> USC-MSA web (English) reference Volume 1, Book 4, Hadith 148 Related
> Qur'an verses
>
> ```
> 33.59
> ```
>
> Narrated `Aisha:
>
> The wives of the Prophet (ﷺ) used to go to Al-Manasi, a vast open
> place (near Baqi` at Medina) to answer the call of nature at night.
> `Umar used to say to the Prophet (ﷺ) "Let your wives be veiled," but
> Allah's Apostle did not do so. One night Sauda bint Zam`a the wife of
> the Prophet (ﷺ) went out at `Isha' time and she was a tall lady. `Umar
> addressed her and said, "I have recognized you, O Sauda." **He said so,
> as he desired eagerly that the verses of Al-Hijab (the observing of
> veils by the Muslim women) may be revealed**. So Allah revealed the
> verses of "Al-Hijab" (A complete body cover excluding the eyes).
>
> https://quranx.com/hadiths/33.59

Comment: In my case i just wanted someone to explain me the hadith i did merely question it because i had some doubts. Now allhamdulilah its more clear.

Comment: Please focus on answering the question asked, and avoid inserting tangential information that distracts from that.